# Cannot Resolve Implicit for Unmarshalling

Tags: scala, spray

Given this simple spray app, which tries to get a response of `Foo` back.

```
object Main extends App with SimpleRoutingApp {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")

  case class Foo(x: String) 
  implicit val format = jsonFormat1(Foo)

  val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[Foo] = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[Foo]

  val LOGIN_URL = "foo.bar.com/login"

  startServer(interface = "localhost", port = 8080) {
    path("go") {
      get {
        complete {
          val req = Post(LOGIN_URL)
          pipeline(req).recoverWith[Foo]{ case _ => Future { Foo("foo") } }
        }
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following compile-time error:

```
[error] Main.scala:19: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type spray.httpx.unmarshalling.FromResponseUnmarshaller[net.Main.Foo]
[error]   val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[Foo] = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[Foo]
[error]                                                                      ^
[error] Main.scala:35: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[net.Main.Foo]
[error]  required: spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable
[error]           pipeline(req).recoverWith[Foo]{ case _ => Future { Foo("foo") } }
[error]                                         ^
```

I had expected that the `implicit val format = ...` would've provided an implicit `Format` for `Foo`.

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: Did you try including `import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._` ?